Unit testcase with parameterized class fixture in Pytest framework is throwing error
I am new to pytest framework. I need to create a testcase with a parameterized fixture on a class. I have created the testcase as below. But it is throwing an error saying:
TypeError: TestClass.test_case_parameterized() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
Please someone help on this
import pytest
import unittest
from moto import mock_aws

@pytest.mark.parametrize("filename", ["testFile1.txt", "testFile2.txt"])
@mock_aws
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_parameterized(self, filename):
        print(f"filename = {filename}")

        #further aws api call processing`


You are mixing unittest and pytest - using pytest fixtures in a Python unittest won't work. Don't derive your test from unittest.TestCase.

If you want to use pytest framework, do not derive your TestClass from unittest.
you can change your code as below:
import pytest
from moto import mock_aws

@pytest.mark.parametrize("filename", ["testFile1.txt", "testFile2.txt"])
@mock_aws
class TestClass:
    def test_case_parameterized(self, filename):
        print(f"filename = {filename}")
        # further aws api call processing
        # your assertion




What did you change from their original code? Please [edit] your answer to clarify what was wrong with the original code, and how your code resolves that.

Use the parameterized library for compatibility with unittest: (https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/)
import unittest
from parameterized import parameterized

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @parameterized.expand([["testFile1.txt"], ["testFile2.txt"]])
    def test_case_parameterized(self, filename):
        print(f"filename = {filename}")

